# How do I take the derivative of $\text{trace}(XX^TY^TYXX^T)$ with respect to the matrix $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, trace, multivariate-polynomial

Given the matrices $Y$ and $X$, I am trying to compute the derivative of the function $f(X,Y) = \text{trace}(XX^TY^TYXX^T)$ with respect to $X\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$. I am aware of the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) but I can not find a way to apply any of the given formulas. Shall I compute the derivative as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990915/how-do-i-take-the-derivative-of-ab-cdot-ctab-cdot-c-with-respect-to) and use the direction $E=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix? Is there an alternative way with less computations?

Comment: Thank you all for you answers. Please give me some time to process. Also, @Arctic Char gave a simple and intuitive answer but deleted it in the end. I hope to re-post it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the deleted answer. The reason I tried that is because I have found the deleted answer simple enough for me to understand it easily.  However, the result I take is the transpose of the answer given by the remaining users. Could you please take a look what I am doing wrong? As soon as it is corrected I will accept the answer of some other user and close the post. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am adding this answer as this might add some additional insight into how these derivatives could be computed. Thus, we will start with some prerequesites:

Consider the mapping $$f : \mathbb{R}^{d\times k} \times \mathbb{R}^{l \times d} \to \mathbb{R} \\
X,Y  \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(XX^TY^TY XX^T)$$

First, we note that by the cycling property, we can also equivalently write this as
$$f(X,Y) = \operatorname{tr}(XX^TXX^TY^TY) = \langle XX^TXX^T,Y^TY\rangle,$$
where $$\langle A, B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$$
is a scalarproduct on the space of $d\times d$ matrizes.

Now, what is a derivative? If we take the notion of Frechet derivative, then losely a derivative is the linear mapping that best approximates our function at a given point. That is, the derivative at $X$ is a mapping
$$D_f(X): \mathbb{R}^{d\times k} \to \mathbb{R} $$
which is linear and has $$f(X+h) - f(X) - D_f(X)(h) = o(h)$$.

But now we can ask, how does a linear mapping from the space of $ d\times k$ to the reals actually look like? By Riesz, we know that such a mapping takes the form

$$D_f(X)(h) = \langle h, M(X)\rangle,$$
where $M(X)$ is a $d \times k $ matrix. Thus, we can identify the derivative with this matrix.

With this definition, it is also relatively easy to see two things: For a linear mapping, the derivative is obviously equal to the mapping itself. For a multilinear mapping $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$, the derivative is obtained by componentwise applying the mapping while leaving the other components fixed, i.e.
$$ D_g(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n) (h_1,h_2,...,h_n) = g(h_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n) + g(x_1,h_2,x_3,...) ...$$
This especially also applies to the scalar product.

Now we are ready to compute the derivative of our function $f$. The first thing we note, is that by the bilinearity of the scalar product and the fact that $Y^TY$ does not depend on $X$, and applying the chain rule we have

$$D_f(X)(h) = \langle D_g(X)(h),Y^TY\rangle ,$$
where $g(X) = XX^TXX^T$. Now we notice that $g$ is again a multilinear mapping in $X$ and we obtain

$$D_g(X)(h) = hX^TXX^T + (hX^TXX^T)^T + Xh^TXX^T + (Xh^TXX^T)^T.$$

In principle we would now be done calculating the derivative, in the sense that we can describe it as the linear mapping

$$ h \mapsto \langle D_g(X)(h),Y^TY \rangle.$$

However, there is one point that still bothers us here: The scalar product in the above definition is on the space of $d \times d$ matrizes, and not on the space of $d \times k$ matrizes, as we have suggested. Also, the result is not in the form  $\langle h, M(X) \rangle$ yet.
We can however now use the fact that a linear mapping has an adjoint operator:

$$ \langle D_g(X)(h),Y^TY \rangle = \langle h, D_g(X)^*Y^TY \rangle,$$
where $D_g(X)^*$ is precisely defined such that this equation holds and on the right side the scalar product is now computed on the space of $\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$.

With some algebra we find that the adjoint of the mapping $D_g(X)$ is given by
$$D_g(X)^*(A) = 2*(XX^TAX + A XX^T X).$$

Thus, combining all our considerations, we find that the derivative of $f$ is identified with the matrix

$$ D_f(X) = 2(XX^T Y^TY X + Y^TY XX^T X).$$

Answer (score 3):

Chain Rule, using convention $AXB' = (A\otimes B)\cdot X$ and rule $\frac{{\rm d\,} }{{\rm d} X} \|\mathbf P X\|^2 = 2\mathbf P' \mathbf P X$ for 4th-order tensor $\mathbf P$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{{\rm d} \|YXX'\|^2}{{\rm d\,} X}
&=\frac{\partial \|YXX'\|^2}{\partial (X, X')} \frac{\partial (X, X')}{\partial X}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial \|YZX'\|^2}{\partial Z=X}
,&  \frac{\partial \|YXZ\|^2}{\partial  Z=X'} 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial X}{\partial X} \\ \frac{\partial X'}{\partial X} \end{bmatrix}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial \| (Y\otimes X)\cdot Z\|^2}{\partial Z=X}
,&  \frac{\partial \|(YX\otimes \mathbb I)\cdot Z\|^2}{\partial Z=X'} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\\&= 2\begin{bmatrix} 
(Y\otimes X)'\cdot(Y\otimes X)\cdot X 
,& (YX\otimes \mathbb I)'\cdot(YX\otimes \mathbb I)\cdot X'
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\\&= 2\begin{bmatrix} 
(Y'Y\otimes X'X)\cdot X 
,& (X'Y'Y X\otimes \mathbb I)\cdot X'
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\\&= 2\begin{bmatrix} 
Y'Y X X'X
,&   X'Y'Y X X^T
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\\&= 
2(Y'Y X X'X + XX'Y'YX)
\end{aligned}$$

which coincides with result obtained from http://www.matrixcalculus.org.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\t#1{\operatorname{Tr}\lr{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \t{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F\\
}$$
And for typing convenience, let's define the symmetric matrix variables
$${A=XX^T,\qquad B=YY^T }$$
Write the function using the above notation.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= B:A^2 \\
df &= B:(A\,dA+dA\,A) \\
 &= (A^TB+BA^T):dA \\
 &= (AB+BA):(dX\,X^T+X\,dX^T) \\
 &= (AB+BA+B^TA^T+A^TB^T):(dX\,X^T) \\
 &= 2(AB+BA)X:dX \\
\grad{f}{X} &= 2(AB+BA)X \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:** The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a Frobenius product to be rearrange in variety of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= AC^T:B = B^TA:C \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:B &= B:A \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce an answer a user posted but finally deleted it. In the deleted answer the equations $(1)-(4)$ are given where $(1)-(3)$ are taken from the matrix cookbook.

$$\partial \text{trace}(X) =  \text{trace}(\partial X)\tag{1}$$

$$\partial (XY) = \partial(X) Y + X \partial (Y) \tag{2}$$

$$\partial X^T = (\partial X)^T \tag{3}$$

Then $$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\partial \text{trace}(XX^T Y^TYXX^T) &= \text{trace}\left(\partial\left(XX^T Y^TYXX^T\right)\right) \\&= \text{trace}(\partial(X)X^T Y^TYXX^T) + \text{trace}(X(\partial X)^T Y^TYXX^T) \\&+ \text{trace}(XX^T Y^TY(\partial{X})X^T) + \text{trace}(XX^T Y^TYX (\partial X)^T)\end{aligned}\end{equation} \tag{4}$$

Using basic trace properties we have
$$\text{trace}(\partial(X)X^T Y^TYXX^T)= \text{trace}(X^T Y^TYXX^T\partial X)$$

$$\text{trace}(X(\partial X)^T Y^TYXX^T) = \text{trace}(X^T XX^TY^TY \partial X)$$

$$\text{trace}(XX^T Y^TY(\partial{X})X^T) = \text{trace}(X^TXX^T Y^TY \partial{X})$$

$$\text{trace}(XX^T Y^TYX (\partial X)^T) = \text{trace}(X^TY^TYX X^T \partial X) $$

Then, taking a closer look at the examples in [[1]](https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf) from $(4)$ we get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}f(X,Y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial X}\text{trace}(XX^T Y^TYXX^T) = 2\left(X^TY^TYX X^T +  X^TXX^T Y^TY\right).$$

However, the final results is the transpose of the result other users provide why is that?

Comment: Getting a transposed result could just be a result of convention, there are [several ones in matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). In so-called numerator layout, $\frac{\partial \frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2}{\partial X} = X'$, whereas $\frac{\partial \frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2}{\partial X} = X$ in denominator layout. And then there are also so-called  mixed layouts, which for example [matrixcalulus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/documentation#layout) uses.

Comment: In principle, it would be better // more consistent // rigorous to adopt a lower/upper // left/right index convention. Personally, I have found the convention that $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X} = \Big(\frac{\partial f(X)_{\mathbf i}}{\partial X_{\mathbf j}}\Big)_{\mathbf i,  \mathbf j}$ with multi-indices $\mathbf i$, $\mathbf j$ to be easy to remember and generalize to arbitrary order tensors. The one thing one needs to remember then is that when tensor-contracting two tensors we should combine the right multi-index of the left operand with the left multi-index of the right operand.

Comment: So the result in the post is in numerator layout? If yes this means that the operator in matrix cookbook are in numerator layout? Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$, what is the convention we can follow such that the results is in denominator layout? That is, $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} f(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it from the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I felt like adding another answer to highlight how one needs to be careful when using the chain-rule in a straightforward manner. This time, let's do an additional intermediate step:

\begin{align}
\frac{{\rm d} \|YXX'\|^2}{{\rm d\,} X}
&=\frac{\partial \|YXX'\|^2}{\partial YXX'} \frac{\partial YXX'}{\partial (X, X')} \frac{\partial (X, X')}{\partial X}
\tag{1}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial \|Z\|^2}{\partial Z=YXX'}\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial YZX'}{\partial Z=X}
,&  \frac{\partial YXZ}{\partial  Z=X'} 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial X}{\partial X} \\ \frac{\partial X'}{\partial X} \end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix}2YXX'\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial (Y\otimes X)\cdot Z}{\partial Z=X}
,&  \frac{\partial (YX\otimes \mathbb I)\cdot Z}{\partial Z=X'} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\tag{3}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix}2YXX'\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 
    Y\otimes X
,&  YX\otimes \mathbb I
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\tag{4}
\\&= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    Y'YXX'X
,&  X'Y'YXX'
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb I \\ \mathbb T\end{bmatrix}
\tag{5}
\\&=
2(Y'Y X X'X + XX'Y'YX)
\tag{6}
\end{align}

Now, you may ask: how does the step from (4) to (5) come about?

Well, it's because we have $Y\cdot (A\otimes B)= A'YB$

But how is that consistent with $(A\otimes B)\cdot X = AXB'$? If we had $Y\cdot (A\otimes B)\cdot X$, then

$$Y\cdot (AXB') = Y\cdot \big((A\otimes B)\cdot X\big) = Y\cdot (A\otimes B)\cdot X  = \big(Y\cdot (A\otimes B)\big) \cdot X = (A'YB)\cdot X$$

A contradiction! So what's going on? Is associativity broken? Well no. The point is it would be a contradiction if here "$\cdot$" would mean matrix multiplication. But it doesn't! Here, "$\cdot$" must mean a tensor-contraction over 2 axes, because $(A\otimes B)\cdot X = (A\otimes B)_{ij, kl}\cdot X_{kl}$, after contracting, has two upper/left indices.

So in order to be consistent, $Y\cdot (A\otimes B)\cdot X$ necessarily must be a scalar quantity, and indeed it translates to

$$Y\cdot (A\otimes B)\cdot X = \underbrace{\langle Y \mid (A\otimes B)\cdot X\rangle}_{=\langle Y\mid AXB'\rangle} = \underbrace{\langle (A'\otimes B') \cdot Y \mid X\rangle}_{=\langle AYB' \mid X\rangle}$$

And the apparent contradiction disappears. Now, one can try and use a colon notation "$:$" like greg likes to do, and I am sure that that is a useful thing in many circumstances, but of course it only goes so far. What is if we now need to do 3d or 4d-tensor contractions?

Comment: $\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}$For higher-order tensor contractions,
Index Notation is the only sensible way work, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
dY_{ijk\ell} &= G_{ijk\ell\c{pqr}}\;dX_{\c{pqr}} \quad\iff\quad
G_{ijk\ell pqr} = \left(\frac{\partial Y_{ijk\ell}}{\partial X_{pqr}}\right) \\
}$$ The term in parentheses is an ordinary element-wise scalar derivative.

Comment: @greg I agree that a (multi-) index notation is a sensible thing to, in my comment to /u/darkmoors own answer I proposed pretty much the exact same thing you write here. However, at the same time, index notation can become a bit annoying. For a while now, I have been wondering of what a good system of rules would be to avoid having to carry them around explicitly. When performing the chain rule it seems that really all one needs to remember is the input/output spaces in the individual terms in the chain rule because they will uniquely determine the associated tensor contractions.